# ios sdk - get device setting value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to know the value of a setting of the device (in specific - of an IPhone) from within the code (Objective C). In particular I wish to know if 3G is enabled (usually undeg settings ->General->Network). 
I Don't wish to change the setting in any way, just to know its current value.

If it is possible to know if a 3G network is available then it's even better. I'm familiar with the Reachability class, however, that would not tell me if the WWAN network is 3G.

Thanks,
Ziv

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1083701/1059705

Comment: I checked this question before posting my question, obviously (cheers for the -1). I look for a way to differentiate a cellular 3G network, from a regular cellular network. Reachability class does not help me with this kind pf problem. I saw many posts that claim that there is no guaranteed way to do it, therefore I'm ready to settle for just knowing the device's setting value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a matter of connection speed, rather than specific abilities of a 3G network (such as voice and data connection simultaneously), then you could probably run some sort of speed test by timing how long it took to load a small file that you know the size of from the internet.

Hope this helps,

Jonathan

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, for replying. It is a good idea, though not a complete solution for me, since I'll probably need to do this check very often at some periods of time, and I probably will need the extra 3G abilities at some point.